# Conditional expectation and stopping times

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, stopping-times

I think I found a way to prove a result but I have doubts about it. I may have made a mistake. ($X$ is a geometric Brownian motion and I do not want to use the strong Markov property)

I have proved that for any $t \in [0,\infty)$ 
$$
\mathbb E\bigg[\int_t^\infty G(X_u)~\bigg|~F_t\bigg]= U_t \tag 1
$$
for a certain function $G$ such that it is well defined and a certain process $U$.

Can I conclude that for any finite stopping time $\tau$:
$$
\mathbb E\bigg[\int_\tau^\infty G(X_u)~\big|~F_\tau] 
= U_\tau \text{ ?}
$$
I think it is true since for any $\omega \in \Omega$ and (I am not sure about this part because it looks too obvious) we get:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\bigg[\int_\tau^\infty G(X_u)~\bigg|~F_\tau\bigg](\omega)&= \mathbb E\bigg[\int_{\tau(\omega)}^\infty G(X_u)~\bigg|~F_{\tau(\omega)}\bigg](\omega) \tag 2 \\ &= U_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)
\end{align}
since $\tau$ is finite and by $(1)$.

But is $(2)$ true and do you know how to prove it? I read on one forum that it is true and it is called "local property of conditional expectation" but I did not find it anywhere else.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit: Does anyone know? It is important because I proved a result using this property and my proof will be wrong if this property is not correct.

Comment: I **disproved** a very similar claim, rather recently. Were you already the author of the previous question? (I remember in particular a similar injunction "It is important because I proved a result using this property and my proof will be wrong if this property is not correct".) Re the present post, identity (2) is much too vague and too sloppily stated for a proof/disproof to be even possible.